# How can I push a byte in a buffer in C?

Tags: c, i2c

I have to send via I2C a buffer with data pixel but first, I have to patch the buffer with an extra byte with the command for the display. How can I do this in C?

```
//
//  Send a data byte sequence to the GDDRAM
//
static void ssd1306_WriteData(uint8_t *buffer,uint16_t length)
{
     uint8_t data[2] = {

     CNTRL_BYTE_SEND_DATA, /* 0x40 */

     buffer /* this does not work, I try to find a way to combine two buffers */

     };

    HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(&SSD1306_I2C_PORT,SSD1306_I2C_ADDR,data,length,timeout);
}
```

In details, I have the Low level I2C function, which has as argument a pointer uint8_t data for the buffer to be sent via the bus and the length of the buffer.

I want to write a function for the application software, with which the app can send a buffer to the display, but first the bus has to send to the display controller, a command that a data flow is coming.

I can't call transmit twice because then the controller will send the slave address on the bus twice.

I don't want to use `memcpy`.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `memcpy`?

Comment: you want `data[1]` to be a byte from `buffer` or you want `data` to contain all the data from `buffer`?

Comment: @yano I want the data buffer to contains the CNTRL_BYTE_SEND_DATA at the begining and the rest elements will be the elements of the buffer.

Comment: @JohnKugelmansupportsMonica I want to avoid the overhead of the memcpy but if it is oneway, then I should be use memcpy.

Comment: is this form STM32?  Because they have a ton of examples sources with the HAL SDK.

Comment: only way to get data from multiple locations into contiguous memory is copy it. Maybe you could initialize `buffer` to be 1 bigger than it needs to be, and start storing the data at `buffer[1]` instead of `buffer[0]`, then write the control byte to `buffer[0]` before you send it?

Comment: @yano but in this case,I have to copy the data from Ram in Stack and this is not good for the memory i think. Very huge usage of non volatile mem.

Comment: not sure I'm following. Ram is volatile memory. Are you frequently writing to flash memory and are worried about exceeding its write cycle count? I'm no hardware expert but I've never heard of read/write count concerns with ram.

Comment: @yano sorry, I mean volatile..typo error

Comment: your ram will survive copying data around. Depending on your dataset size it might all live in the cache for a while anyway. If you have speed/power usage concerns, then that's something else, but if your main concern here is "wearing out" your ram, don't worry about it.

Comment: You have to either call the function twice, or make a new buffer with all of the data you want to transmit stored contiguously... there are no alternatives

Answer (score 0):

First `malloc()` a buffer with the extra length. Then use `memcpy()` to place `0x40` and then copy the buffer. I always did it a little bit different with bytes.

```
volatile uint8_t data[2];
data[0] = address | 0x40; // multibyte write enabled
data[1] = value;
```

In your case you need to use `malloc() & memcpy()`, because you are not sure what length is to send.

Another solution will be to send the first `0x40` and then send the rest of the buffer (idk if this works in your case).

Or keep that extra byte in mind and do `buffer | 0x4000` where the total amount of zeros is your offset that you can easily made with `uint32_t variable = 0x40;` and then `variable << length*2;`. With this method you have to keep in mind the extra buffer length.

Answer (score 0):

Preallocate a working buffer which covers the maximum command size which is 65536 bytes as your size is 16bit + the command header size. You could allocate an extra page so you can align the memory. Then commands can be copied and dispatched with a simple memcpy. Perhaps you did not want to use memcpy because of the allocation of temporary buffer required. Does this help?